# Shopify access redirects with Javascript api

Tags: ajax, url, redirect, shopify

Can we access url-redirects via Shopify's ajax api? I am currently doing some programming in javascript, where I have the need to access url-redirects.

Comment: Do you mean the redirects that are listed here? https://myshopify.com/admin/redirects

Comment: Yes. Exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

No, URL redirects are not available from Shopify's ajax APIs. You can fetch them [using the Shopify admin API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/redirect) but keep in mind that it is not safe to call this API from a frontend script. It has call limits and you don't want to expose your OAuth access token/API password.